# how to solve invalid conversion specifier warning in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilabel

I have iphone app in which assigning value to label but when i build this it shows following warning invalid conversion specifier $

here is the code of label assigning values.

```
label1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%$",newvalue1];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace like this why you keep `%$` simply place `$` symbol

`label1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d$",newvalue1];`

Answer (score 8):

The `%$` is being interpreted as a format string specifier. You need to escape the percent in `%$` with two percent signs: `%%$`, or remove the second `%` if you just want a dollar symbol.