# invalid conversion specifier &

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiwebview

This is first time I got warning for particular NSString

I am showing my office co-ordinated on my webview with loading url below.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7CXX.XX95741,XX.XXXXXX
```

But I am getting warning for the character "&" before the word markers and if I removed that "&" it shows me same warning for "%" at position after word red and label.

Because of which I am not able to target exact location on web view url.

Can any one guide me, how to overcome this.

I searched lot of SO, but didn't find perfect answer.

Also my next target is,
I am opening the above link on `UIWebview` and when user clicks on `UIWebview` then I want to open MAP application with same location. Is it possible....?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the warning that you get?

Comment: Invalid conversion specifier '&'

Comment: When do you get this? when you assign it to an NSString variable?

Comment: yes at the same time

Comment: I tested this right now NSString *lala=@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7CXX.XX95741,XX.XXXXXX"; and i did not get any warning. Are you sure that this is the error?

Comment: yes, its not error
but warning is giving which result a blank screen of map view
Why this warning is there don't know

Comment: can you share your sample url *lala

Comment: Please post your code for the string above. Here it is how i pass the string to the url:  NSURL *lala=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7CXX.XX95741,XX.XXXXXX"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer,

Removed %20 and replaced %7C with |

As the url that I received was encoded URL
So after removing that got the perfect URL

Comment: Yes. There is a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140488/how-to-solve-invalid-conversion-specifier-warning-in-iphone-app